# Combining 2 angles as

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Given are 2 right angle triangles. $\triangle PAB$ and $\triangle PBC$ such that $PA=16$, $AB=12$ and $BC=21$. Express the value of cos $\angle APC$  in the form $\frac{x}{y}$, where x,y are integers. $\triangle PBC$ sits on $\triangle PAB$ such that $PB$ is the hypotenuse of $\triangle PAB$ and the base of $\triangle PBC$.

I have found $PB$ by pythagoras to be 20 and used this to determine $PC$ to be 29. To express $\angle PAC$ it is possible to combine $\angle APB$ and $\angle BPC$ like this; $cos(\frac{16}{20}) + cos(\frac{20}{29})$ or is the another way?

Comment: Where is right angle for PBC?

Comment: $\angle{APC}=arccos(\frac{16}{20})+arccos(\frac{20}{29})$.  I don't know what form you want.

Comment: @greedoid $PC=29$ makes $PC$ the hypotenuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw the triangle. Common vertex is at $P.$

No, $\cos(p1+p2)\ne\cos p1 + \cos p2 $. We have

$$ \cos \angle APC= \cos(p1+p2)=\cos p1 \cos p2-\sin p1\sin p2$$

$$= \dfrac{ 16 }{20  } .  \dfrac{ 20 }{ 29 }- \dfrac{12  }{ 20 } .  \dfrac{21  }{29  } =  \dfrac{ 17 }{145  } .$$

[image: Comb Ang Cos]

Comment: Answer should be $\frac{16}{29}$ - $\frac{63}{145}$ = $\frac{17}{145}$

Comment: Thanks, corrected  typo.error